# How to call injected javascript function in iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
var iFrameHead = document.getElementById('myFrame');
var myscript = iFrameHead.contentDocument.createElement("script");

myscript.type = "text/javascript";
myscript.src = "myFile.js";
myscript.text=console.log("hai hello");
iFrameHead.contentDocument.head.appendChild(myscript);

setTimeout(saveData(),500);
```

It showing `saveData()` not defined.

Injected javascript in iframe, `saveData()` is a function inside the myFile.js, how to call fun from injected page itself.